# ACF, post object in woocommerce Cart

Tags: woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I hope it's a dumb question, but I can't find a smart solution at the moment.

I've got a custom field in my products page - which is a Relationship field - and I'd like to display a field of my RF for every product in my cart page.

More specifically: I have a product associated with a brand. The brand has a 'shipping time' field.

At the moment my function is partially working, in the sense that it displays the request value, but ONLY for the first item in the cart.
That's my code in function.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'wc_add_shipping_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function wc_add_shipping_to_cart( $cart_data, $cart_item ) 
{ 

$custom_shipping = array();

if( !empty( $cart_data ) )
    $custom_shipping = $cart_data;

// Get the product ID
$product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
$custom_field_value = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'brand_select', true );
$display_brand_shipping = get_field('shipping_time_brand', $custom_field_value); 

if( $custom_field_value = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'brand_select', true ) )
    $custom_shipping[] = array(
        'name'      => __( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'     => $display_brand_shipping,
        'display'   => $display_brand_shipping,
    );

return $custom_shipping; }
```

Could you help me?

Comment: How is associated the product with the brand? Is the brand a custom  taxonomy or a product attribute? What is the taxonomy for this brand? Is the brand is set for the product (just as product categories or product tags does)?

Comment: 'brand' is a custom post type, I associated a product to it through a Relationship field

Comment: Sorry but i can't help more as it's too custom to guess what is not working.

Comment: uhm what kind of information would you need? I've a cpt called ' brand ', where I've some fields ( shipping time, website, etc ). I have some products associated to a brand through a Relationship field. 
Gaven this relation, I'd like to show, on the cart page, a field from the brand associated

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not testable as is not possible to reproduce your issue related to product custom field and ACF fields, but it can be simplified this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'wc_add_shipping_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function wc_add_shipping_to_cart( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) 
{ 
    if( $brand_select = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], 'brand_select', true ) ) {
        if( $shipping_time = get_field('shipping_time_brand', $brand_select ) ) {
            $cart_item_data[] = array(
                'name'      => __( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value'     => $shipping_time,
            );
        }
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Comment: Thanks, this works too. Unfortunately, my problem remains.